# Angular material button text disappears when loaded in view of ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I am using generator-angular-fullstack, with angular-material and ui-router.

My `client/index.html` has

```
<div layout="column" flex="100">
        <md-toolbar>
            <md-button ng-click="wb.toggleLeft()">Left</md-button>
            header
            <md-button ng-click="wb.toggleRight()">Right</md-button>
        </md-toolbar>
    </div>
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div ui-view="" layout="column" flex="100">
```

And I am loading the view in the `ui-view` with:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views:{
            '@':{
                templateUrl: 'assets/layouts/dashboard_layout.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'wb'
            },
            'header@dashboard':{
                templateUrl: 'assets/layouts/partials/dashboard_header.html',
            }
        }
      });
```

And the html in `assets/layouts/dashboard_layout.html` is

```
<md-toolbar>
    <md-button flex ng-click="wb.toggleLeft()"> Left </md-button>
    header
    <md-button flex ng-click="wb.toggleRight()"> Right </md-button>
</md-toolbar>
```

Now when I visit `/dashboard`, the `md-toolbar` that is set in `index.html` shows up properly, but the one which gets loaded in the `ui-view` container seems to be missing the `Left` and `Right` button labels, and I get empty buttons on that.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Edit:** It seems, the error isn't related to ui-view, because the button labels disappear in the plunkr too.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3Uot9N1bh4smjHgOs8P?p=preview

Comment: can you create plunker  that will be helpful

Comment: Is there any console error?

Comment: @shakib , nope no errors

Comment: @rupesh_padhye Please see the plunker added above

Answer (score 1):

Check below plunk ,`Toolbar buttons` are showing text,Left Navigation is also added

[Working link](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQUBTy?p=preview)

Mistakes in your plunk:

1.You were injecting $materialSidenav instead of $mdSidenav

> In 0.4.1 $materialSidenav was renamed to $mdSidenav.